# Solve the following recurrence $b(n)=0.9*b(n-1)+60, b(1)=300$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How to solve the following recurrence: $$b(n)=0.9*b(n-1)+60, b(1)=300$$

I do it with telescoping, like this:

$$b(n)=0.9*(0.9*b(n-2)+60)+60$$
$$b(n)=0.9*(0.9*(0.9*b(n-3)+60)+60)+60$$

Which means that for $n=4$ we get $$b(n)=0.9^{(n-1)}*300+(60)^n-1$$

But the correct solution is $b(n)=-300*(0.9^n)+600$

Can someone please explain where is my mistake?

Comment: Looks like a geometric sum to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_n = ab_{n-1} + c, b_1 = d$. Then by expanding, one gets: $b_n = a(ab_{n-2} + c) + c = a^{n-1}b_1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{a^ic}$. Finally $b_n =a^{n-1}d + c\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$.

Comment: This answer is a better one since it does not depend on any choice to nullify a part of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$b_{n}=a_n+c$$
So we have that
$$a_n+c=0.9(a_{n-1}+c)+60$$
$$a_n=0.9a_{n-1}+60-0.1c$$
So if we let $60-0.1c=0$, we get that $c=600$. But this means that
$$a_n=0.9a_{n-1}$$
Which I think you can solve. From this, we will get that
$$b_n=a_n+600$$